# two sets of same php code with same version working differently on two different servers?

Tags: php, oop, class

I made a class that converts a string of text into a png image and uploads on the server:

http://testing.mehhh.org/php/png.php   (you can view php source on the page)

http://testing.mehhh.org/php/phg.php <-- shows php version

this one works great.

now I am trying to get this to work on a clients server

http://autoxplorer.com/~tameem/png.php  This doesn't work!

http://autoxplorer.com/~tameem/php.php <-- also using same php version

what gives?  I thought it's a permission thing.. but the png folder has full access.. and I tried a super simple uploading script and it runs and saves files to that folder.  What is going on here?

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you sure they have the same extensions installed ie-> GD for imagecolorallocatealpha? The php version is not the only thing that matters.

Comment: Do both servers have the arial.ttf file referenced?

Comment: Have you check the error logs? The link to the first phpinfo has a "g" instead of a "p" so it doesn't work, corrected one: http://testing.mehhh.org/php/php.php

Comment: its the stupid stuff that gets you.  i was missing the font

Answer (score 1):

You have just put online some PHP scripts that link to images. The link to the images actually *is* different.

1. http://testing.mehhh.org/php/png/4de9441d68cf8_1307132957.png
2. http://autoxplorer.com/~tameem/png/4de9424d41208_1307132493.png

While the first link returns actually an image, the second image link gives a 404 error. Looks like you have not configured your server properly to actually execute the PHP in the second case to return an image.